# making a string samefrom both ends by shifting characters

Tags: java, string

I am given a string `S` and I have to make it a palindrome by re-arranging the characters of the given string.

If the given string can not be converted into a palindrome by re-arranging characters, print false and if it is possible to make it a palindrome, print true

My code:

```
       String a=new String(br.readLine());      //given string
   int n= a.length();   
                    int j=0,k=n-1,count=0;
        boolean flag=false;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(a.charAt(i)=='*')
                continue;        //for skipping already shifted  chars
            int ix = a.indexOf(a.charAt(i), i+1);
            if(ix >= 0)
            {                   a=a.substring(0,i+1)+a.substring(i+1, ix) + "*" + a.substring(ix+1);
            }
            else
            {
                count++;        //number of unique chars which can only be 1 or 0
                if(count<=1 && n%2==1)
                {

                    a=a.replaceFirst(a.substring(i,i+1),"*");                  //giving middle position to the only unique char at center and replacing it with *
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("false");    //if more than one unique char, palindrome not possible
                    flag=true; // shows not possible
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        if(!flag) // if possible
        {                   
            System.out.println("true");
        }
```

Comment: I think this question would be a better fit for the Stack Exchange site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). The problem seems a little too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It is hard to understand whats going on with the code, explain your algorithm from a high level point of view. To me the approach would be : if the two ends do not match, first check for a matching char from right if it is there swap their positions, if a matching char not found, try the left. Then remove them , and keep working on the remaining string. Base case is either you have one character or two characters ( check for equality there ). If you couldn't find a character to swap return false.

Comment: Do you mean you have to find a combination of the characters that is a palindrome?

Comment: At first glance, you rely to much on string operations. Couldn't you work with individual characters instead?

Comment: @Mauriceperry yes, I want to find the combination of chars of the given string which will make make it a palindrome and return their new positions

Comment: updated my code after reducing string methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious optimization would replace:

```
        if(a.substring(i+1).contains(a.substring(i,i+1)))
        {
            ans[j++]=i;                           //storing new positions in ans array
            ans[k--]=a.substring(i+1).indexOf(a.charAt(i))+1+i;
            a=a.substring(0,i+1)+a.substring(i+1).replaceFirst(a.substring(i,i+1),"*");                 //replacing the shifted char with *
        }
```

with:

```
        int ix = a.indexOf(a.charAt(i), i+1);
        if(ix >= 0)
        {
            ans[j++]=i;                           //storing new positions in ans array
            ans[k--]=ix;
            a=a.substring(0,i+1)+a.substring(i+1, ix) + "*" + a.substring(ix+1);
        }
```

UPDATE

I wonder if the following code would be faster. There is no indexOf on arrays, so I had to do a loop, but there is no string manipulation:

```
    char[] c = a.toCharArray();
    int n= c.length;  
    int ans[]=new int[n];  // for storing new positions after shifting
    int j=0,k=n-1,count=0;
    boolean flag=false;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char ch = c[i];
        if(ch=='*')
            continue;        //for skipping already shifted  chars
        int ix = i;
        do {
            ++ix;
        } while (ix < n && c[ix] != ch);
        if(ix < n)
        {
            ans[j++]=i;                          
            ans[k--]=ix;
            c[ix] = '*';
        }
        else
        {
            count++;        //number of unique chars which can only be 1 or 0
            if(count<=1 && n%2==1)
            {
                ans[(int)n/2]=i;
                c[i] = '*';
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("-1");   //if more than one unique char, palindrome not possible
                flag=true; // shows not possible
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

UPDATE 2

You can also stop when j has reached n/2:

```
    char[] c = a.toCharArray();
    int n= c.length;  
    int ans[]=new int[n];  // for storing new positions after shifting
    int j=0,k=n-1,count=0,half=n/2;
    boolean flag=false;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char ch = c[i];
        if(ch=='*')
            continue;        //for skipping already shifted  chars
        int ix = i;
        do {
            ++ix;
        } while (ix < n && c[ix] != ch);
        if(ix < n)
        {
            ans[j++]=i;                          
            ans[k--]=ix;
            c[ix] = '*';
            if (j > half) {
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            count++;        //number of unique chars which can only be 1 or 0
            if(count<=1 && n%2==1)
            {
                ans[half]=i;
                c[i] = '*';
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("-1");   //if more than one unique char, palindrome not possible
                flag=true; // shows not possible
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: will it reduce the time complexity that much ?will it work  for n=10^5?

Comment: @sahilmehta It reduces the number of string operations, and it will definitely be faster, that said, You'd be better of with a `char[]`instead of a String.

Comment: @sahilmehta or in addition to a String

Comment: you mean I should operate the code on char[] instead of string?

Comment: your suggested code was helpful it reduced the time complexity a bit but still code is exceeding time limit for a test case in n=10^5

Comment: @sahilmehta the complexity doesn't change: it's still O(n^2), but from what I have measured, the last version is like 100 times faster than the original one.

Comment: thanks. your code works fine with the constraints and within time limit.